# Flying-sphinx and Heroku scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Because I'm a newbie at FS, Heroku and Rails I am having trouble implementing the scheduler rake task.

I build a scheduler.rake in my lib/tasks folder and set up the following:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :index_sphinx => :environment do
  puts "Indexing Sphinx db..."
 ???flying-sphinx index???
  puts "done."
end
```

As you can see we have a problem because I have no idea how to type the flying-sphinx index command in the task - what format the command is supposed to take.

The Heroku FS [doco](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/flying_sphinx#processing-sphinx-indices) states to "just add flying-sphinx index as the task" but this doesn't tel me exactly how to type it down - it probably requires a little background knowledge I still don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution 0 though I understand from Pat (the founder of FS) there is a simpler one.

First, mine:

```
system 'flying-sphinx index'
```

And his:simply type:

```
bundle exec flying-sphinx index
```

in the scheduler dashboard.

Hope this has been useful to someone.